# Value of server side li element not showing in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, html-lists

I have a ul list in which the values are set from the database. I want to get the li value to a jquery alert function. But it does not working. **However same function works when I want to retrieve ul list values from a client slide list.**

How can I retrieve values of ulList(server side values)?

```
    <ul runat="server" id="ulList" onclick="ul_Click">
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
```

Script for alert function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#list2 li").click(function(){
      var selected=$(this).html();
      alert(selected);
    })
    </script>
```

How ulList get values

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection("Server=NIPUNA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=XXXX; Trusted_Connection=True");
    string[] itemList = authorList();
    foreach (string item in itemList)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl newLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        //newLi.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"Books.aspx?bookId=" + item + "\">" + item + "</a>";
        //newLi.InnerText = item;
        newLi.InnerHtml = "<b>" + item + "</b>";
        ulList.Controls.Add(newLi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is runat server you should access as below

jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/QNUWh/

this gives you the id for the jquery.

```
<%= ulList.ClientID %>

var TestID = '#' + '<%= ulList.ClientID %>';
```

you will get id and then you can bind the events.

if you want the value you should use

```
.text();
```

`.html()` gives you the html

Comment: I put it like this but it's not working.     <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ulList li").click(function(){
        var TestID= '#' + '<%= ulList.ClientID %>';
        alert(TestID);
    })
    </script>

Comment: yes it's working when i'm doing with just Jquery,HTML but when I retrieving values from Database it's not working. That's the issue

Comment: @Nipuna , you should acess the way i mentioned for server side values , do one thing , do viewsource , get the div id which will have clientid also and give a try , this is just for debugging , once that works we can make it generalized with id.clientID ok

Answer (score 0):

use `text()` to retrieve  li value...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#list2 li").click(function(){
      var selected=$(this).text();
      alert(selected);
    })
    </script>
```